# What is the evidence for and against the HOD conjecture?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, inner-model-theory

I'm aware that the HOD conjecture is implied by the Ultimate-L conjecture, but I don't know what the evidence is for the Ultimate-L conjecture. On the other hand, I'm aware the evidence against the HOD conjecture is that the consistency of ZF + Berkeley cardinals disproves the HOD conjecture, and the evidence from the theory of Berkeley cardinals seems to indicate that they are consistent with ZF. What is the main evidence for both sides, and what is the expert consensus at the moment on the HOD conjecture?